# Convert large number of Android.mk files to CmakeLists userInclude

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, android-source, clion

I am working on a project that is a derivative of AOSP, and would like to be able to use CLion to edit the C++ portions with code support.

As I understand it, the main thing keeping me from doing so is that I need to include all of the items that Android.mk is including. I can compile via mma, but builds from within Clion fail because it can not parse the #include  commands..

Is there any way to traverse the existing Android.mk files to create a proper Cmakelists file that will allow Clion to give code support? 
Is this possible at all?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think anything exists as such. If all you want is the editing features and don't care about building it might be possible. I would start with getting the toolchain and the sysroot into cmake. I think trying to get the whole code base is going to shutdown your IDE. In fact android has an ide_gen tool that generates and Andoid studio project. The IDE kept hanging for me. Might be better to scope your projects down to the relevant libraries for your task.